# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in C that I can't comprehend, debug or fix

Tags: c, arrays, image, exc-bad-access, allocation

I'm new to C and, to be honest, I have some problems with it. I'm trying to parse an image file and, in order to do that, I create an array that is supposed to contain each pixel. This array is called `jmpr_pixel** pnmPixels` (`jmpr_pixel` being a structure that I defined in my class's header-file). I allocate the memory needed for this array using the following code:

```
pnmPixels = malloc(pnmSize.height * sizeof(jmpr_Pixel));
for (i=0; i<pnmSize.height; i++) 
{
    pnmPixels[i] = malloc(pnmSize.width * sizeof(jmpr_Pixel));
    if (pnmPixels[i] == NULL) 
    {
        printf("An error occured while allocating memory.");
    }
}
```

Later, I assign values to the array by using `pnmPixels[row][column] = pixel`, the latter being a `jmpr_pixel`-structure. When I run the code, an error (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT`) occurs for seemingly random values:

```
row = 448
column = 0
```

The picture is 5390 times 1133 pixels large.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help debugging this problem.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hint: you are missing a `*` in the very first line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @PaulR, but I fail to find the place where I missed a `*`.

Comment: OK - just before the last two closing parentheses - you're allocating an array of pointers here, not pixels.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, and it seems to have solved my problem (after also fixing other problems my code had …). Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome - I would have written a proper answer but I'm on a mobile device.